# Exporting SPList

Tags: splistitem, export

I'm iterating SPWebs and SPLists. When those lists fulfil specific requirements, I would like to export the lists in code, and later import them to another SharePoint environment (using code).

How should this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want something along the lines of the Content Deployment Wizard by our very own Chris O'Brien:

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/12/introducing-sharepoint-content.html

Available for download here:
http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/

Comment: I forgot to mention one important detail in my question; I will export from SP 2003 and import to SP 2007. Will this be a problem using this tool? I see from one of the comments on the page by Peter that he has sucsessfully done this, but the description on codeplex says this is a tool for SP 2007/2010.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend using [Gary Lapointe's custom STSADM](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/stsadmpowershell-commands/) commands. You can call the stsadm commands from a console application using [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).

I needed to keep the list's people fields intact which is why I chose [gl-exportlist](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2007/09/importexportcopy-lists/).

Another reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378553/sharepoint-copy-a-list-to-a-different-web

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you will need to use [SPImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.deployment.spimport.aspx) and [SPExport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.deployment.spexport.aspx) classes. Here is an article, which explains, how to work with them:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/SPCopy.aspx