# How to copy surveys from Sharepoint 2007 to 2010?

Tags: 2007, survey-list

We are just preparing to roll out Sharepoint 2010. Is it possible to copy the handfull of surveys we have on SP 2007 to the new server? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Have you seen [my answer to this question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12005/exporting-splist/12010#12010)? Though I don't think it keeps Created/Created By info..

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option for you: create the surveys and save them as templates in 2007. Take those templates and create a site collection with a single site and use those templates to create one of each of the survey's you are wanting to move. Move the database and attache it to 2010 to upgrade the database and the content. Go into the site and make sure the surveys work. Take those surveys and make 2010 templates from them and then deploy them where needed in 2010. However, if you need the entire site and survey, the easiest would just be to attach the content database and upgrade.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It seems that when the survey is recreated from the template, all the author and timestamp info is lost. That might not be a problem for us but I'm guessing it will be - I'll have to check

Answer (score 1):

Just found this:

**Copy a list from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010 site using web service**

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/33a934f9-7fbc-4658-8a6a-69b45ae31594/

Answer (score 1):

If your survey is its own site you can move the SQL db, and attach it to the new farm, which will perform an upgrade of the site to 2010 and preserve the content.

Comment: unfortunately not