# how to backup a SPList with 25000 records including attachements on SP2007

Tags: 2007, list, backup

On SP2007 there is a sharepoint list (SPList) with 25000 records. The records contain attachements. In SP Designer 2007, the list has a size of 64MB.

How can a backup be created ?

Options investigated:

1. Save as Template (incl content): gives an error message: "Failure decompressing data from cabinet file". So this is no option.
2. Export to Excel: No option, since attachements need to be backed up also.

How should you resolve this ?

Regards,

André

Comment: Because of #1/#2 you're going to have to do this via stsadm so get one of your sp admins involved

Comment: Have you seen http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12005/exporting-splist/12010? I'm leaning towards this question being a duplicate but I'll wait to see what everyone else things.

Comment: Here Dre has only sitecollection-level privilegies, so I don't really think it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If you have farm privilegies, you can use this tutorial for export-import approach:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx

Comment: Thanx for the hint. Unfortunatly, I don't have Farm privs. (also this is SP2007, not 2010, concepts might be the same)